# Using pointers for image objects in opencl

Tags: opencl, gpu, gpgpu

I am trying to read the image objects using a pointer instead of 2D image object buffer

```
  img_fmt.image_channel_order = CL_R;
  img_fmt.image_channel_data_type = CL_UNORM_INT8;
__kernel void test(__read_only image2d_t in, __write_only image2d_t out)
{
    float *p;
    void *temp;
    temp = (void *)&in;
    p=temp;

    if(get_global_id(0) == 10)
    printf("%f",*p);

}
```

However when I get the print of this I see all the values as zero's.
I want to do this

1) find out the reason why its happening?

2) if the above works I want to use vload16 on pointer p to get 16 pixels in one go? I don't think its possible to get 16 pixels from the address of the image object, but I want to see what is there in memory at that address?

One more interesting thing I saw when I just print the address of in on each work item id. Using below code:

```
__kernel void test(__read_only image2d_t in, __write_only image2d_t out)
{
    float *p;
    void *temp;
    temp = (void *)&in;

    if(get_global_id(0) < 50)
    printf("%p",temp);

}



0x500000000 row no 0 col no 0      0x500004000 row no 0 col no 4      0x500008000 row no 0 col no 8     0x50000C000 row no 0 col no 12     0x500000080 row no 0 col no 16  0x500004080 row no 0 col no 20
0x500000008 row no 0 col no 1      0x500004008 row no 0 col no 5      0x500008008 row no 0 col no 9     0x50000C008 row no 0 col no 13     0x500000088 row no 0 col no 17  0x500004088 row no 0 col no 21
0x500000010 row no 0 col no 2      0x500004010 row no 0 col no 6      0x500008010 row no 0 col no 10    0x50000C010 row no 0 col no 14     0x500000090 row no 0 col no 18  0x500004090 row no 0 col no 22
0x500000018 row no 0 col no 3      0x500004018 row no 0 col no 7      0x500008018 row no 0 col no 11    0x50000C018 row no 0 col no 15     0x500000098 row no 0 col no 19  0x500004098 row no 0 col no 23

0x500000020 row no 1 col no 0      0x500004020 row no 1 col no 4      0x500008020 row no 1 col no 8     0x50000C020 row no 1 col no 12     0x5000000A0 row no 1 col no 16  0x5000040A0 row no 1 col no 20
0x500000028 row no 1 col no 1      0x500004028 row no 1 col no 5      0x500008028 row no 1 col no 9     0x50000C028 row no 1 col no 13     0x5000000A8 row no 1 col no 17  0x5000040A8 row no 1 col no 21
0x500000030 row no 1 col no 2      0x500004030 row no 1 col no 6      0x500008030 row no 1 col no 10    0x50000C030 row no 1 col no 14     0x5000000B0 row no 1 col no 18  0x5000040B0 row no 1 col no 22
0x500000038 row no 1 col no 3      0x500004038 row no 1 col no 7      0x500008038 row no 1 col no 11    0x50000C038 row no 1 col no 15     0x5000000B8 row no 1 col no 19  0x5000040B8 row no 1 col no 23

0x500000040 row no 2 col no 0      0x500004040 row no 2 col no 4      0x500008040 row no 2 col no 8     0x50000C040 row no 2 col no 12     0x5000000C0 row no 2 col no 16  0x5000040C0 row no 2 col no 20
0x500000048 row no 2 col no 1      0x500004048 row no 2 col no 5      0x500008048 row no 2 col no 9     0x50000C048 row no 2 col no 13     0x5000000C8 row no 2 col no 17  0x5000040C8 row no 2 col no 21
0x500000050 row no 2 col no 2      0x500004050 row no 2 col no 6      0x500008050 row no 2 col no 10    0x50000C050 row no 2 col no 14     0x5000000D0 row no 2 col no 18  0x5000040D0 row no 2 col no 22
0x500000058 row no 2 col no 3      0x500004058 row no 2 col no 7      0x500008058 row no 2 col no 11    0x50000C058 row no 2 col no 15     0x5000000D8 row no 2 col no 19  0x5000040D8 row no 2 col no 23

0x500000060 row no 3 col no 0      0x500004060 row no 3 col no 4      0x500008060 row no 3 col no 8     0x50000C060 row no 3 col no 12     0x5000000E0 row no 3 col no 16  0x5000040E0 row no 3 col no 20
0x500000068 row no 3 col no 1      0x500004068 row no 3 col no 5      0x500008068 row no 3 col no 9     0x50000C068 row no 3 col no 13     0x5000000E8 row no 3 col no 17  0x5000040E8 row no 3 col no 21
0x500000070 row no 3 col no 2      0x500004070 row no 3 col no 6      0x500008070 row no 3 col no 10    0x50000C070 row no 3 col no 14     0x5000000F0 row no 3 col no 18  0x5000040F0 row no 3 col no 22
0x500000078 row no 3 col no 3      0x500004078 row no 3 col no 7      0x500008078 row no 3 col no 11    0x50000C078 row no 3 col no 15     0x5000000F8 row no 3 col no 19  0x5000040F8 row no 3 col no 23
```

Each 4x4 tile is stored in continuous address space. Actually there is pattern to store the tiles Like 0th and 4th 4x4 block are also contiguous in memory.

I am not able to connect all things. If anyone can help that will be wonderful.

Comment: Version is opencl 1.2

Comment: In the first code snipped you are printing values of pointer pointing to nowhere.

Comment: thanks It was a mistake during writing the question.. I have corrected the question now.

Comment: OpenCL image types are opaque  because it allows them to be Z ordered  ( see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve) to improve memory. So that  physically adjacent pixels are stored in consecutive memory locations.

Comment: Even if it is in Z order. Why I am  getting only zero's?

Answer (score 0):

You simply cannot do what you are trying; the `image2d_t` type is *not* a pointer. If your particular implementation happens to let you get at something that looks like image data using it that way, it is just an artifact of the implementation and you can't expect it to be portable or even work with the next driver version.

Perhaps what you want is device memory you can access either as a buffer or as an image. If so, use the `cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer` extension.